# echo values of an array into jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flot

So I am using FLOT to generate some bar graphs and it uses some javascript arrays to allow for the data. I have a query that spits out the correct labels and values as so:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($chart_stats)){

printf("Race is: %s Percentage: %s", $row['Race'],$row['Percentage'] ."<br/>");
```

}

My question is can I get the values of my array from php into the array of Javascript (if that makes sense)

```
    var d1 =[0, 72]; //instead of static value maybe var d1 = [0,<?printf($row['Percentage'])?>];
    var d2 =[1,3];
    var d3 = [2,40];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can `echo` stuff from PHP wherever you like. When putting it into a block of JavaScript, though, you have to be careful that:

- The resulting output is ALWAYS valid code
- There is no way for user-generated input to be placed into code and run

The second one is simple: never put anything you got from `$_POST` into a `<script>` tag.

As for the first, [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode) is a big help. With it, you can output almost any kind of PHP variable as a valid JavaScript one.

Comment: About use of `$_POST`: you can use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to circumvent XSS attacks, can't you?

Comment: Yes, you can, but that won't protect you if you dump the content directly into a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Beautiful! This spits out my values in an array like so: "76.9""21.0""15.6""2.8""2.4""1.9""0.3""0.0" How can I get these values indivdually into each one of those javascript vars?

Comment: If you just put `var myarray = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>` (assuming the right variable name) the result will be a JavaScript array, which you can then use in any way you like.